# webkit.messageHandlers not working on iPad

Tags: javascript, ios, webview, app-store

**Summarize the problem**

I registered my iOS app on the App Store, but it was rejected.
Basically it works fine on iPhone.
But I've heard that there is a feature that doesn't work properly on the iPad.
The app partially has a webview.
In my tests, it didn't work on iPads (15.2, 15.1). It may not work on older versions as well.
Calling webkit.messageHandlers from webview not working

**Describe what you’ve tried**

At the beginning of the project we developed using modern JavaScript syntax.
However, the import/export syntax in iOS version 14.2 caused problems and fixed code compatibility issues with webpack.
I haven't tried the solution because I can't figure out why iPhones and iPads behave differently.

**My Code**

```js
import { checkAndroid, checkIos } from "../../js/utils/index.js";

const step1El = document.querySelector("#step1");
const step2El = document.querySelector("#step2");
const btnEl = document.querySelector("button");

btnEl.onclick = function () {
  if (!step1El.checked)
    return alert("블록체인 간편인증 서비스 이용약관에 동의해주세요");
  if (!step2El.checked)
    return alert("개인정보 수집 및 이용 동의서에 동의해주세요");

  if (checkAndroid()) window.Android.agree();
  if (checkIos()) webkit.messageHandlers.agree.postMessage(""); // not working on iPad
};

document.querySelector(".tos_btn").onclick = () => {
  if (checkAndroid()) window.Android.goTermsConditions(true);
  if (checkIos()) webkit.messageHandlers.goTermsConditions.postMessage(true); // not working on iPad
};
document.querySelector(".policy_btn").onclick = () => {
  if (checkAndroid()) window.Android.goCollectionAgreement();
  if (checkIos()) webkit.messageHandlers.goCollectionAgreement.postMessage(""); // not working on iPad
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

The problem was my mistake.

The problem was in the checkIos function

before

```js
export function checkIos() {
  const userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
  if (userAgent.indexOf("iphone") > -1)
    return true;
  return false;
}
```

after

```js
export function checkIos() {
  const userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
  if (userAgent.indexOf("iphone") > -1 || userAgent.indexOf("ipad") > -1)
    return true;
  return false;
}
```